# I reused a Mixamo animation for my modified Mixamo model. But, the origin is offset from the mesh in this animation. Animation not working as intended

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, dopesheet, origin

I was adding some modeling tweaks to a character model in Blender that I had previously exported from Mixamo. I wanted to use the "Strike Forward Jog" animation from Mixamo, so I imported another version of that model with this animation into Blender. In Blender I renamed the animation to Kick_04 and I added the animation to my modified model using the Action Editor.

When I play the animation the character bounces around the screen frantically. It appears that the character still pulls off the kicking animation, however she keeps spawning on different areas of the screen each frame. I think this has to do with the fact that both the mesh and the armature's origin is offset in this animation. Could the animation have different local coordinates that are clashing with the Models local coordinates and its relationship with the blender files global coordinates?

I tried putting the armature and mesh's origins to the world origin of (0,0,0). I then moved the armature and mesh so that they stand right on top of the world origin, however I can only figure out how to apply this shift to one frame at a time, and I am worried I might alter the animation itself if I apply these local transforms to all the keyframes.

Oddly enough in edit mode the Mesh and Armature are both correctly placed right above the world origin, with their origins placed in-between the feet at (0,0,0). I just can't find a way to have the animation play in that location in pose and object mode.

I'd appreciate any help on how to fix this issue.

Thank you!

[image: Model at frame 1 in object mode]
Model at frame 1 in object mode

[image: Model at frame 1 in edit mode]
Model at frame 1 in edit mode

[Video of Blender Animation error[3](https://youtu.be/cKYIBIoGu5Q)
(I apologize for the poor video quality)

Comment: Just suggestion ... Upload your edited model to Mixamo, run through auto-rig system, assign mocap you like and export. One more thing ... I see you have Rigify in use ... Mixamo's rig doesn't match Rigify's ... It means anim would not work without proper retargeting process.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the scale values have been applied, so animation data have an uncorrect scaling.

If so, you have to go to graph editor, select all and only location data of hip bone and scale them on Y (value) by 0.01 (or whatelse other scale has been applied).

If this doesn't solve the problem, please upload your file.

Comment: Josh Sanfelici, that fixed it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Izzy ... If answer solved your issue, consider mark the answer as Accepted. Thank you keep this site organized.